# Finding the files which are not accessed/modified in last 30min?

Tags: bash, shell

I've one requirement, i want to give the notifications to the users who have not accessed the files in `30 min`. using the shell script. Is it possible to find the files which was not accessed in `30 min` using find. I'd checked.

```
find /opt/SP/tibmft/scripts/ -mtime 0
```

which will fetch the files which was modifed in last 24 hours.

My requirement is fetch the files which was created in the last 30 min and not been accessed by the user? Please suggest the solution, how to achieve this?

Comment: i think ls -l gives you list along with last modification time

Comment: Most Unix filesystems don't record file creation time. They just have modification, access, and inode change times.

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
find PATH -cmin -30 -and -amin +30
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to find the files which was not accessed in 30 min using find.

According to `man find`:

> Numeric arguments can be specified as
>
> - `+n`     for greater than n,
> - `-n`     for less than n,
> - `n`      for exactly n.

Please note, this is *greater* and *less* not greater/less *or equal*. So, you have to take some care in order to not have a 1 minute error due to that:

```
find PATH -not -amin +30
```

or

```
find PATH -amin -31
```

---

> My requirement is fetch the files which was created in the last 30 min and not been accessed by the user?

Here is an attempt:

```
find PATH -amin -31 -not -newerBt "-30 minutes"
#                        ^^^^^^^^
#                        (B)irth date newer (t)han ...
```

... unfortunately, it does not work on my computer with *ext4* file-system, as, to quote a comment by `Barmar` above: *"Most Unix file-systems don't record file creation time. They just have modification, access, and inode change times."*

Some random ideas:

- According to one of your comment, this is potentially a periodic task. So one might investigate the use of a [*cron job*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to record the list of files at regular intervals?
- If your file-system has [*snapshots*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29) you might build on that too. Maybe.

Comment: I'll agree with this but how to prevent fetching all the files, i need the files which were created only on the current day.?

Comment: @Sushma Could you confirm: "created today" and "not accessed in the past 30 minutes"?

Comment: The current script will run in the interval of 30 min, to check the files which were created in the last 30 min but had not accessed/modified?

Comment: @Sushma You didn't mention it was a periodic task. Due to FS limitations, you can't go on using a simple `find` command for that. You will have to somehow record the list of files at a given time. And use that in the following runs to check for "new files" -- eventually using `find` on those files to check access time. May I suggest you do some experiments that way, and, if needed, to ask _an other_ question?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
find $PATH -type f -cmin -30 amin +30
```