# What is the difference between find options -cmin and -amin?

Tags: shell, datetime, find

Reading [Finding the files which are not accessed/modified in last 30min?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24953576/802365) I'm puzzled by the difference between *change time* and *access time*.

Could you elaborate on the difference and source your statements?

Answer (score 12):

Based on [Find the Time of Access, Change & Modify File in Linux & Unix](http://itsiti.com/find-the-time-of-access-change-modify-file-in-linux-unix):

- **Access** is referring to the last time the file was **read, view or displayed** (*e.g.* `more`, `less`) ;
- **Modify** means when was the last the file **content was modified** (*e.g.* `vi`) ;
- **Change** term was determined by when was the last **meta data of the file been modified** (*e.g.* `chmod`, `chown`).